# Can I use my IOS device (Iphone) to test my IOS flutter (or react native) app in Windows?

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter, react-native, mobile

I know you need a Mac in order to build and test IOS apps using cross-platform frameworks, but is there any way I can use  an IOS device instead to test out my app while I build it.

The only resources I can find are about using virtual machines to emulate a Mac but sadly my PC isn't that powerful to run both OS smoothly

Comment: The virtual machines running on non-Apple hardware do not put you in compliance with the Apple license.  So it's a good thing you're not trying that. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: No.
You need a macOS operating system to build/compile an iOS app. No matter whether it has been coded with flutter, react native, ionic or native swift.

You could rent a Mac online, so that you don't need physical access to one. But in the end, you will need macOS somewhere.
If you rent a Mac you will have difficulties running the app directly on your phone. You will need to create the IPA and distribute it via a different connection to your phone.

Comment: oh ok, thank you very much for answering and I'll try renting instead

Comment: an example of a service https://www.macincloud.com/