# flutter - generating an IPA file without Xcode or apple product

Tags: ios, flutter, ipa

I am developing an app using flutter but I'm using windows. Is there a way to generate an IPA file without Xcode & without the usage of any apple product?

Edit: I don't have any apple products and understood that virtualizing mac won't help and I don't intend to rent a macOS so other questions related to the topic that already got posted before aren't answering my question unfortunately

Comment: Basically, you can't.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use my IOS device (Iphone) to test my IOS flutter (or react native) app in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74245119/can-i-use-my-ios-device-iphone-to-test-my-ios-flutter-or-react-native-app-in)

Comment: You can use a code build CI service in the cloud or rent a Mac in the cloud

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Understood there is no actual solution to this. you HAVE to own an apple product or rent a mac
Even renting / virtualizing a mac / using a code build CI service have some issues at the end.